# Pocketbase "Failed to load the submitted data due to invalid formatting"

Tags: node.js, express, multer, pocketbase

Pocketbase should let me submit using formdata but this is not the case, im using multer to upload first then to Pocketbase, any suggestions to do this better would be helpful!

```
///index.js post part
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  if (!req.file) {
    console.error('No file received');
    return;
 }
 console.log(req.file.filename);
 console.log(req.file.path);
 const formData = new FormData();
 //formData.append( req.file.filename, fs.createReadStream(req.file.path), req.file.filename );
 formData.append('title', 'Hello world!');
console.log(formData);
const createdRecord = pb.collection('File_ImagesStoring').create(formData);

 res.redirect('/');
 
});
```

```
///upload.js

const multer = require('multer');

// Set up storage for uploaded files
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

// Create the multer instance
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

I tried switching buffers and others

Comment: Can you share what `File_ImagesStoring` is?